# How to hide video loading spinner in HTML5 video tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Problem is on slow 3g connection it continuously shows spinner even when video is loaded and it is playing.

Code:

```
<video src="d3cvwyf9ksu0h5.cloudfront.net/answer-1530971608.mp4" preload="auto" autoplay controls controlslist="nodownload" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></video>
```

Comment: Please check video on this link on slow 3g connection https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/a-contractor-estimates-that-3-persons-could-rewire-jasminders-house-in-4-days-if-he-uses-4-persons-i-5224

Answer (score 5):

The spinner element is a shadow DOM (`-internal-media-controls-loading-panel`) that can't be styled with CSS or removed by JavaScript. You can, however, hide its parent element and implement custom video controls. You can do it either by adding:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls { /* Works only on Chrome-based browsers */
    display: none;
}
```

or simply removing the `controls` tag from the video element.

Here's an example from [blog.teamtreehouse](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos) that works on most popular browsers. The loading spinner is hidden along with all default video controls. You can style the controls however you want:

```js
const waitForLoad = (video, cb) => {
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{
        if(video.readyState >= 3){
            clearInterval(interval);
            cb();
        }
    }, 100);
}
window.onload = function () {
    const video = document.getElementById("video");
    // Wait for the video to load 
    waitForLoad(video, () => {
        // We can't call video.play directly, because it can only be initiated by a user gesture 
        alert(`The video is loaded, you can click "Play"`);
    });

    // Implement the custom controls
    const playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");
    const muteButton = document.getElementById("mute");
    const fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("full-screen");

    const seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
    const volumeBar = document.getElementById("volume-bar");
    
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (video.paused == true) {
            video.play();
            playButton.innerHTML = "Pause";
        } else {
            video.pause();
            playButton.innerHTML = "Play";
        }
    });
    muteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (video.muted == false) {
            video.muted = true;
            muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute";
        } else {
            video.muted = false;
            muteButton.innerHTML = "Mute";
        }
    });
    fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (video.requestFullscreen) {
            video.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
        } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
        }
    });
    seekBar.addEventListener("change", function () {
        var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
        video.currentTime = time;
    });
    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
        var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;
        seekBar.value = value;
    });
    seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
        video.pause();
    });
    seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
        video.play();
    });
    volumeBar.addEventListener("change", function () {
        video.volume = volumeBar.value;
    });
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="video-controls">
        <button type="button" id="play-pause">Play</button>
        <input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0">
        <button type="button" id="mute">Mute</button>
        <input type="range" id="volume-bar" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1">
        <button type="button" id="full-screen">Full-Screen</button>
    </div>
    <video src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" id="video" width=320 height=192></video>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

On Chrome and Chrome-based browsers you can achieve this with this small trick:

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls {
     visibility: hidden;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
     visibility: visible;
}
```

#### Demo

```html
<head>
  <style>

    video::-webkit-media-controls {
         visibility: hidden;
    }

    video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
         visibility: visible;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <video src="//commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" width="320" height="180" controls autoplay></video>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a React app where
I needed the controls when the video is playing, but for the loading phase I needed to show a custom image ("poster" in the code below) without the loading spinner.
I set a state to flag when the Video is loaded, and the set the control attribute to that state:

```
    <video 
          autoPlay 
          id="video" 
          width="100%;" 
          className='video-style' 
          controls={videoLoaded}
          poster={poster}
          onCanPlayThrough={handleLoaded}
          onPlay={handlePlay}
          >
```

```
    const handleLoaded =  () => {
      setVideoLoaded(true)
    }
    const handlePlay = () => {
      setVideoLoaded(true)
```

```
const [videoLoaded, setVideoLoaded] = useState(false)
```